# Problem with intalling indigo on 64bit trusty

Tags: ros, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I try to install Indigo on a 64bit ubuntu trusty, I run into the following problem :

```
olivier@GeckoTech:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

What is the problem, does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203771/problem-with-intalling-indigo-on-64bit-trusty/) by [OlivierL](https://answers.ros.org/users/19636/olivierl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this 14.04.2 by any chance?

See if the answer by @demmeln in [Ubuntu 14.04.2 unmet dependencies](http://answers.ros.org/question/203610/ubuntu-14042-unmet-dependencies/) helps you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OlivierL](https://answers.ros.org/users/19636/olivierl/) on 2015-02-25**:
It was indeed, and the solution suggested by your link worked, thanks a lot!